# SQL запрос - конструкция IF(EXISTS()) в MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Подключаюсь к MS Acess через VBA (ADODB.Connection).
SQL запрос выдает ошибку.
Конструкция такая:

```
IF(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM (имя таблицы, где ищется запись) WHERE (условие, которое должно выполниться)))
        BEGIN
            UPDATE (имя таблицы, где ищется запись)
            SET (данные, которые будут обновляться)
            WHERE  (условие)
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT  INTO (имя таблицы, где ищется запись)
            VALUES()
        END
```

Отдельно UPDATE работает, но в конструкции IF(EXISTS()) нет.

Comment: Увы-увы... Access такого не позволяет. Выполните два запроса - INSERT, потом UPDATE - это будет быстрее.

Comment: @Akina , получается, мне необходимо выполнить проверку прежде чем INSERT? Суть в том, что я хочу обновить то, что присутствует и добавить то, чего нет в БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Преобразуйте эту конструкцию в два запроса:

```sql
INSERT INTO ( имя таблицы, где ищется запись )
VALUES ( значения для вставки )
/* если вставляемые значения могут НЕ привести к нарушению уникальности, раскомментировать */
/* WHERE NOT ( условие, которое должно выполниться ) */
```

```sql
UPDATE ( имя таблицы, где ищется запись )
SET ( данные, которые будут обновляться )
WHERE ( условие )
  AND ( условие, которое должно выполниться )
```

Да, если вставляется строго одна запись, то можно посмотреть количество записей, вставленных первым запросом, и если единица, то не суетиться со вторым.